# JQuery ajax redirect change part of JSP page if success else change in Popup form

Tags: java, jsp, jquery, struts2

I have a JSP page. I am using struts2. This is my JSP page

[image]

As you can see  there is form above and another accordion showing some items. **Components** showing a list of components. And has one **ADD** button. When I click on Add buton, it will call one Ajax call and will return HTML, which I am setting to a **DIV** and displaying it as a popup form.

[image]

After I enter data, and click on save, it will call the Ajax and save to database. Then it will redirect to another action to get the updated list and return the list to ajax. That result I am displaying inside Components Tab.
[image]

It is working. Now, in the popup form some fields are required and if do not enter those it will call action class (action validator.xml file is used to validate the required fields.)
And will return the error, but as its ajax call, the resultant data will be setting inside the components Tab.

[image]
(The error message shown here is error of another form. But the same will be displayed for this form also. Below to that error message, form will also display. All will be inside the Components Tab)
 I want the error result to be displayed in same popup form.

**Jquery Ajax**

```
$(document).on('click', ".saveRow", function(){
        var formId=$(this).closest("form").attr("id");
        var form = $("#"+formId);
        var htmlId=formId;
        htmlId=getDivId(htmlId);
        form.submit(function () {
            $('.saveRow').html('Saving...').fadeIn();
            var urlAction=form.attr('action');
            var dataFields=form.serialize();
            callActionUsingAjax(urlAction, dataFields, function (data) {
                    var ajaxActionResult=ajaxResult(data);
                    setHTMLContent(ajaxActionResult,htmlId);
                    $('.popUpForm').dialog("close");
            });
         return false;
        });
    });

function callActionUsingAjax(urlAction, dataFields, callback)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: urlAction,
                data: dataFields,
                success: function (data) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
        }

    function ajaxResult(data)
    {
        var ajaxResult= $('<div/>').html(data),
        $ajaxContent = ajaxResult.find('#ajaxContent');
        var ajaxActionResult=$('<div/>').html($ajaxContent);
        ajaxActionResult.find('#ajaxContent').removeClass("crudItems");
        ajaxActionResult.find('#resultContent').removeClass("includestyle");
        ajaxActionResult.find('#ajaxContent').find("#footer").remove();
        return ajaxActionResult;
    }

    function setHTMLContent(ajaxActionResult,htmlId) {
        $("#"+htmlId).html(ajaxActionResult);
        $("#"+htmlId).height(315);
    }
```

In the ajax success if i give `alert(data);` it alerts with whole html text. I tried `alert(data.redirect)` and it alerts with **"undefined"**.

**My struts.xml**

```
<action name="saveDimComponent" 
    class="com.vxl.appanalytix.webapp.action.DimComponentAction"
    method="save">
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/dimComponentForm.jsp</result>
    <result name="cancel" type="redirectAction">dimComponents</result>
    <result name="delete" type="redirectAction">dimComponents</result>
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">dimComponents</result>
</action>
```

(ie, if result is *input*, it should show the popup form with errors)

**UPDATE 1**

**DimComponent-validation.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
    "http://web.archive.org/web/20090222210559/http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="dimComponent.componentId">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message key="errors.required"/>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="dimComponent.componentDesc">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message key="errors.required"/>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

**DimComponentAction-validation.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
    "http://web.archive.org/web/20090222210559/http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="dimComponent">
        <field-validator type="visitor">
            <param name="appendPrefix">false</param>
            <message/>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

**DimComponentAction.java**

```
public class DimComponentAction extends BaseAction implements Preparable {

   private List dimComponents;
    private DimComponent dimComponent;
    private Long componentKey;
    private String query;

    @Autowired
    private DimComponentManager dimComponentManager;

    //getter and setter

    public void prepare() {
        if (getRequest().getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
            // prevent failures on new
            String dimComponentKey = getRequest().getParameter("dimComponent.componentKey");
            if (dimComponentKey != null && !dimComponentKey.equals("")) {

                dimComponent = dimComponentManager.get(new              Long(Integer.parseInt(dimComponentKey)));
            }
        }
    }
   public String list() {
        try {
           dimComponents = dimComponentManager.search(query, DimComponent.class);
        } catch (SearchException se) {
            addActionError(se.getMessage());
            dimComponents = dimComponentManager.getAll();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String delete() {
        dimComponentManager.remove(dimComponent.getComponentKey());
        saveMessage(getText("dimComponent.deleted"));

        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String edit() {
        setComponentValues();
        if (componentKey != null) {
            dimComponent = dimComponentManager.get(componentKey);
        } else {
            dimComponent = new DimComponent();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String save() throws Exception {
        if (cancel != null) {
            return "cancel";
        }

        if (delete != null) {
            return delete();
        }

        boolean isNew = (dimComponent.getComponentKey() == null);

        dimComponentManager.save(dimComponent);
        String key = (isNew) ? "dimComponent.added" : "dimComponent.updated";
        saveMessage(getText(key));

        if (!isNew) {
            return INPUT;
        } else {
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're using the `success` callback in jQuery for both successful requests and requests that aren't processed successfully. Unfortunately, your server code forces you to do so, because apparently there is no way you can deduct from the response body that the request was not successfully processed. The Struts action result is not incorporated in the HTTP response, so you need to find another way to differentiate between the outcomes.

If you change your server side code to set an error code when the input is not valid (for example, `400 Bad Request`). If that is in place, you can change your jQuery code like so:

```
function callActionUsingAjax(urlAction, dataFields, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: urlAction,
        data: dataFields,
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Somehow process the validation messages,
            // like you seem to be doing already.
        }
    });

    // etc...
}
```

Now you have two callbacks: one that is called when the request was successful, and another one that displays the error popup. The latter may even be re-usable over multiple pages :).

Comment: No other method for this? Because I have so many pages like this. All are created using Appfuse. It has action validator xml and form validator xml. In action class there is no validation is happening and not returning if required field is empty

Comment: If the `Action`s do not perform validation, who/what does? Maybe you can update the question with an example of how server side validation is done?

Comment: I mean I don't know how it is not performing the validation for required field. It is struts2 and for each from, each validator.xml file is there. I'll update the question with file content

Comment: sorry for late reply. I have Updated the code with xml files and action class

Comment: Have you followed [these instructions](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/validation.html#Validation-TurningonValidation) in order to turn on validation?

Comment: It is on. That is why it is showing the error messages. I only want to check whether the result is `input` or not. If it's input I may be able to display the data in popup form. So if ajax returns success also, I want to check whether the result is "`input`". How can I check that in ajax success function?

Comment: @ShijuKBabu You can't send the result with the status, my be JSON is a better approach.

Comment: Then, how to send as JSON? I mean I want the result HTML content as well as result status

Comment: @ShijuKBabu Then you need a JSON plugin that is able to send your action properties to the client and return result type "json".

Comment: Can u show some example or link which returns HTML content as well as result status?
In my Project, I am using Jackson